# Is there a way to change the Addition action between 2 occurrence? (In Boolean query)

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring, booleanquery

I have the next Query:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {

      "must" : 
        { "term" : 
          { "message" : 
            {
              "value": "message",
              "boost": 2.0 
            }
          } 
        },
        "should" : 
        { "term" : 
          { "message" : 
            {
              "value": "message",
              "boost": 2.0 
            }
          } 
        }
    
    }
  }
}
'
```

The `_score` that I get from this response is multiple by 2 of `_score` (which I get without one of the scopes (`must` / `should`) )
My question is if there is a way to change the action to multiple instead of addition 
 **for example** - instead `_score + _score` I'll get `_score * _score`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random)

A working example (using script score):

`_score` will be multiplied by `_score`

**Mappings**

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Insert documents**

```
POST index/_doc/1
{
  "message":"message"
}

POST index/_doc/2
{
  "message":"message"
}
```

**Search query without `script_score`**

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "message": {
                  "value": "message"
                }
              }
            }
          ],"should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "message": {
                  "value": "message"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.3862944,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "message"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.3862944,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "message"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search query using `script_score`**

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "message": {
                  "value": "message"
                }
              }
            }
          ],"should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "message": {
                  "value": "message"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": "_score"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.921812,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "message"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.921812,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "message"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, As I see in the explanation of the response, this is not multiplication between the should *  must , is the multiplication between the last score (addition between should to must) and then multiplication, the question is if you could only to change the addition in multipication

Comment: These are 2 different documents. in my example, I showed how to get `_score` of each document to be multiplied by itself. `_score = _score * _score`. As I understood from your question this is what u asked for. Did you want to get `_score = _score (must) * _score(should)`?

Comment: Yes, I mean `_score = _score (must) * _score(should)`

Comment: But what if your query is not combined only from `must` and `should`, what would you do then? I don't think it's possible. for example,  the use of function_score  computes a new score for each document returned by the query. meaning you can affect the `_score` of a document. Either way, I hope my answer will be useful for u.

Comment: If it is not must and should it will by 0 (becouse must_not and filter will return 0 ) but the question is specific for the `must` and `should` combination, I upvote your answer but unfortunately this is not the answer for my specific question. Thanks:)

Comment: Thanks. If you will find it, please post it here. My suggestion is to make use of function_score, I think this is the best approach to start with.